# ForeignField queryset edit inside a modelformset

Tags: django, formset

I have the following model

```
class HasJobs(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
```

And the modelform

```
class HasJobsModelForm(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = HasJobs
```

and in my view I create a modelformset

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(#somefiltering here)
has_jobs = HasJobs.objects.filter(#some filtering here)

hasjobsformset = modelformset_factory(HasJobs, form=HasJobsModelForm)
formset = hasjobsformset(queryset=has_jobs)
```

I want also to set the job field in the jobs query set like i could do If I didn't have to deal with a formset like this:

```
form.fields['job'].queryset = jobs
```

Can this be done in a formset automatically or must I use for in every form I have in the formset something like:

```
for job_form in formset:
    job_form.fields['job'].queryset = jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually subclass `BaseFormset` and provide my own `_construct_form(self, index, **kwargs)`, steering it as my needs be;

a cleaner approach might be to provide a custom `init` method to your `ModelForm` and feed it any parameter you need from the afore mentioned `_construct_form`.